# Pyqt table widget updation

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am inserting some data in qtablewidget after some time interval. For this i am clearing all content of qtable and then inserting data. But the table showing data from first row, I want that the table always show last row. This will feel like real updation of table. how to do this?

Comment: Post the code that isn't working. When you do this, make sure to edit your question instead of just adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the row, call `QTableWidget.scrollToBottom()` to show that last row.